# My Save Method is only saving the Background and not the Draw Image in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a Java GUI that has a panel where you can scribble on it. I want to save the scribbled image after drawing it. However, my save method only saves the background and not the drawing.

Here is part of the constructor for my GUI. The important part is the scribblePane2 object which is the section of the GUI where the image is drawn.

```
public GUI(){

    // Create the main scribble pane component, give it a border, and
    // a background color, and add it to the content pane

    scribblePane = new ScribblePane2();
    scribblePane.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    scribblePane.setBackground(Color.black);

    contentPane.add(scribblePane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   
}
```

Here is the scribblePane2 class where I take the mouse input to draw the image in the panel. The method "lineto" is where I draw the lines in response to mouse input. I tried drawing to the buffered image, bufferImage, but it did not work for me.

```
class ScribblePane2 extends JPanel {

BufferedImage bufferImage;
public ScribblePane2() {
    
   // Give the component a preferred size
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    
    bufferImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    
    Graphics2D bufferGraphics = bufferImage.createGraphics();

}

/** Draw from the last point to this point, then remember new point */
public void lineto(int x, int y) {


    Graphics g = getGraphics();
   
    
    g.setColor(color);
    ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));// Tell it what color to use
    g.drawLine(last_x, last_y, x, y); 

    
    moveto(x, y);
}

public BufferedImage getImage (){
     return bufferImage;

}
```

}

Here is my method to save the image. I tried by creating a Buffered Image of the scribblePane and a doing the screen capture which is the line commented out. Both have not worked.

```
public static void saveDrawing(int i) {
        
      
    BufferedImage imagebuf = null;
    //imagebuf = new Robot().createScreenCapture(scribblePane.getBounds());
    
   imagebuf = new BufferedImage(scribblePane.WIDTH, scribblePane.HEIGHT,  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    //imagebuf = scribblePane.getImage();
    Graphics2D graphics2D = imagebuf.createGraphics();
    scribblePane.paint(graphics2D);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(imagebuf, "png", new File("save" + i +".png"));
        System.out.println("image saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

For reference, here is all of my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;




public class GUI  {
    private static int i;
    private static  JButton button;
    private static JButton button2;
    private static JLabel label;
    private static ScribblePane2 scribblePane;
    private static JPanel contentPane;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint   mPaint;
    //private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    BufferedImage bufferImage;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new GUI();
        setUpButtonListeners();
        // Scribble scribble = new Scribble();
        //scribble.setSize(500, 300);
        //scribble.setVisible(true);
    }




    public GUI(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(300,300);

        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel("number");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Hi I'm contentPane");
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(label2);
        button = new JButton("Classify Image");
        button2 = new JButton("Erase Image");



        // Specify a layout manager for the content pane
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Create the main scribble pane component, give it a border, and
        // a background color, and add it to the content pane

        scribblePane = new ScribblePane2();
        scribblePane.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        scribblePane.setBackground(Color.black);

        contentPane.add(scribblePane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Create a menubar and add it to this window. Note that JFrame
        // handles menus specially and has a special method for adding them
        // outside of the content pane.
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar(); // Create a menubar
        //frame.setJMenuBar(menubar); // Display it in the JFrame

        // Create menus and add to the menubar
        JMenu filemenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu colormenu = new JMenu("Color");
        menubar.add(filemenu);
       // menubar.add(colormenu);

        // Create some Action objects for use in the menus and toolbars.
        // An Action combines a menu title and/or icon with an ActionListener.
        // These Action classes are defined as inner classes below.


        Action black = new ColorAction(Color.black);
        Action red = new ColorAction(Color.red);
        Action blue = new ColorAction(Color.blue);


        // Populate the menus using Action objects


       // colormenu.add(black);



        // Now create a toolbar, add actions to it, and add it to the
        // top of the frame (where it appears underneath the menubar)
        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();


       // contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Create another toolbar for use as a color palette and add to
        // the left side of the window.
        JToolBar palette = new JToolBar();
        palette.add(black);

        palette.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
       // contentPane.add(palette, BorderLayout.WEST);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30,30,10,30));



        panel.setLayout(layout);
        panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(contentPane, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(panel2,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        //gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        //gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(button, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;

        panel.add(button2, gbc);




        //panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //panel.add(button, BorderLayout.WEST);
        //panel.add(button2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        //panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //panel.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(panel);



        frame.setTitle("GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);







    }




    public static void setUpButtonListeners(){


        ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                System.out.println("save");

                int output = 0;


                saveDrawing(i);
                i++;
                label.setText("" + output);

            }


        };

        ActionListener buttonListener2 = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("erase");
                scribblePane.clear();
                label.setText("");

            }


        };
        button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        button2.addActionListener(buttonListener2);


    }

    public static void saveDrawing(int i) {

            //throws AWTException {
        BufferedImage imagebuf = null;
        //imagebuf = new Robot().createScreenCapture(scribblePane.getBounds());
        imagebuf = new BufferedImage(scribblePane.WIDTH, scribblePane.HEIGHT,     BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        //imagebuf = scribblePane.getImage();
        Graphics2D graphics2D = imagebuf.createGraphics();
        scribblePane.paint(graphics2D);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(imagebuf, "png", new File("save" + i +".png"));
            System.out.println("image saved");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
    private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
    {

        System.out.println("load");
        //use a fileInputStream to read the file in a try / catch block
       // try {
          //  File f=new File(path, "drawn_image.jpg");
         //   Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
          //  ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.outputView);
          //  img.setImageBitmap(b);
       // }
     //   catch (FileNotFoundException e)
       // {
      ///     e.printStackTrace();
      //  }

    }



    /** This inner class defines the "clear" action that clears the scribble */


    /** This inner class defines the "quit" action to quit the program */


    /**
     * This inner class defines an Action that sets the current drawing color of
     * the ScribblePane2 component. Note that actions of this type have icons
     * rather than labels
     */
    class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {
        Color color;

        public ColorAction(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
            putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, new ColorIcon(color)); // specify icon
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            scribblePane.setColor(color); // Set current drawing color
        }
    }

    /**
     * This inner class implements Icon to draw a solid 16x16 block of the
     * specified color. Most icons are instances of ImageIcon, but since we're
     * only using solid colors here, it is easier to implement this custom Icon
     * type
     */
    static class ColorIcon implements Icon {
        Color color;

        public ColorIcon(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        // These two methods specify the size of the icon
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return 16;
        }

        public int getIconWidth() {
            return 16;
        }

        // This method draws the icon
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);
        }
    }



}

class ScribblePane2 extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage bufferImage;
    public ScribblePane2() {
        // Give the component a preferred size
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        bufferImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D bufferGraphics = bufferImage.createGraphics();


        // Register a mouse event handler defined as an inner class
        // Note the call to requestFocus(). This is required in order for
        // the component to receive key events.
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                moveto(e.getX(), e.getY()); // Move to click position
                requestFocus(); // Take keyboard focus
            }
        });

        // Register a mouse motion event handler defined as an inner class
        // By subclassing MouseMotionAdapter rather than implementing
        // MouseMotionListener, we only override the method we're interested
        // in and inherit default (empty) implementations of the other methods.
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                lineto(e.getX(), e.getY()); // Draw to mouse position
            }
        });

        // Add a keyboard event handler to clear the screen on key 'C'
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C)
                    clear();
            }
        });
    }

    /** These are the coordinates of the the previous mouse position */
    protected int last_x, last_y;

    /** Remember the specified point */
    public void moveto(int x, int y) {
        last_x = x;
        last_y = y;
    }

    /** Draw from the last point to this point, then remember new point */
    public void lineto(int x, int y) {


        Graphics g = getGraphics();
       /// BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(200,200,
                //BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
     ///   Graphics g = newBufferedImage.getGraphics();
        // Get the object to draw with
        g.setColor(color);
        ((Graphics2D) g).setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));// Tell it what color to use
        g.drawLine(last_x, last_y, x, y); // Tell it what to draw

        //g.drawImage(bufferImage, x,y,null);
        //bufferImage = newBufferedImage;// Save the current point
        moveto(x, y);
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage (){
         return bufferImage;

    }

    /**
     * Clear the drawing area, using the component background color. This method
     * works by requesting that the component be redrawn. Since this component
     * does not have a paintComponent() method, nothing will be drawn. However,
     * other parts of the component, such as borders or sub-components will be
     * drawn correctly.
     */
    public void clear() {
        repaint();
    }

    /** This field holds the current drawing color property */
    Color color = Color.white;

    /** This is the property "setter" method for the color property */
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    /** This is the property "getter" method for the color property */
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621105/save-image-from-jpanel-after-draw

Comment: Your problems start here: `Graphics g = getGraphics();`.  This is returning your the components `Graphics` context, but what's on it is only what was drawn during the last paint pass.  Instead, you should be using the `Graphics` context your created from the `BufferedImage`

Comment: I think you should have a read of [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to get a better idea of how painting works in Swing and how you should be working with it

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Note that neither of adding random classes or methods, nor dumping over 400 lines of all of the code, constitutes an MRE / SSCCE. The self contained code should have **all** extraneous code removed and focus on the problem. It would likely end up as <100 LOC.

Comment: A) thanks for providing code and making sure it is formatted (almost) correctly, 
but B) Please read [mcve]. You really shouldnt just drop ALL your code on other people. Always try to reduce your problem to a **minimal** amount of code. Dont throw so many empty and commented lines on other people. You want other people to spend their free time to help you with your problem, so you please spend the time to make that *easy* to do. And note: reducing your problem to less code often helps you to figure the problem yourself, without help. Which is the best thing that can happen to you.

Comment: In case you misunderstand what the MRE is, note that the latest edits certainly do not include one.